# How to capture CTRL + SPACE +SPACE key presses

Tags: c++, win32gui

How would I capture the user pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>?

I successfully tested the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> with this code:

```
RegisterHotKey(0, 1, MOD_CONTROL, VK_SPACE);
```

Comment: How can you press two space keys?

Comment: Did you add `device=dblspace.exe` to your autoexec.bat?

Comment: I assume you mean "press space + ctrl, then press space again". Is that right?

Comment: Use RegisterHotKey(0, 1, MOD_CONTROL, VK_SPACE | TWO_FINGERS)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill `VK_SPACE | VK_SPACE` is less keystrokes than `VK_SPACE | TWO_FINGERS`. And you can use the convenience macro `VK_SPACES` (note the `S`) as well.

Comment: That is traditionally written `Ctrl+Space, Space`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Programmable keyboard. Ma es  yping  ery di  icul   hough.

Comment: Ernest Friedman-Hill: TWO_FINGERS error: identifier not defined !!!

Comment: @yasso All comments except the first one are jokes. Your request makes no sense. It is impossible to press Ctrl + Space + Space, because there are no two Space keys on the keyboard. Did you actually mean Ctrl + Space, Space?

Comment: lethal-guitar: test in test, yes solution but complicated

Comment: @Dialecticus: yes "ctrl + space + space" to move mon application to another spot

Comment: I assume you did not understand my question, because your answer again does not makes sense. Read again my question. Instead of `+` (plus) there is `,` (comma). Did you mean `Ctrl + Space, (comma) Space`?

Comment: @Dialecticus yes sorry I did not understand your issue,  I can't press two space at the same time,so impossible "ctrl + space + space" is "ctrl + space, space"

Comment: @yasso "ctrl + space + space" is "ctrl, space, space"

Comment: @ta.speot.is yes is "ctrl + space, space" but how would i capture!!!

Answer (score 5):

That is traditionally written `Ctrl+Space, Space`. That is, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

First, RegisterHotKey is system-wide. If you just want multi-level keyboard shortcuts in your application, you should not use RegisterHotKey.

Second, you cannot do this with RegisterHotKey, you have to handle a two-level hotkey by:

- Setting a variable somewhere to say that a multi-level hotkey has begun, and what it is.
- Writing a global keyboard hook, which does the following

  - checks if a hotkey has begun, if not then normal behaviour, otherwise
  - checks for second half of the hotkey. If matched, do correct action.
  - Whether matched or not, cancel the "hotkey-pending" state.

You could register the keyboard hook only when the hotkey is pressed, and unregister it afterwards, or leave it on the whole time.

Comment: I tried RegisterHotKey(0, 1, MOD_CONTROL | VK_SPACE, VK_SPACE) but no result, what is the problem!!!

Comment: @yasso, The problem is that RegisterHotKey **cannot do** what you want. To do what you want, you need to read what I wrote in my answer. Also if this is just for when the user is using your application, RegisterHotKey is the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)` to capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while hitting the <kbd>space</kbd> key.

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) !=0 && key == VK_SPACE )
    {
       MessageBox(NULL, "CTRL-SPACE was pressed\nDo something in here", 
       "H O T K E Y", MB_OK);
       CTRL_key=0;
    }
```

Complete  code to capture CTRL-SPACE:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hKeyboardHook;

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardEvent (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD SHIFT_key=0;
    DWORD CTRL_key=0;
    DWORD ALT_key=0;

    if  ((nCode == HC_ACTION) &&   ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) ||  (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hooked_key =    *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        DWORD dwMsg = 1;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.scanCode << 16;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.flags << 24;
        char lpszKeyName[1024] = {0};
        lpszKeyName[0] = '[';

        int i = GetKeyNameText(dwMsg,   (lpszKeyName+1),0xFF) + 1;
        lpszKeyName[i] = ']';

        int key = hooked_key.vkCode;

        SHIFT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
        CTRL_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
        ALT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU);


        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) !=0 && key == VK_SPACE )
            {
               MessageBox(NULL, "CTRL-SPACE was pressed\nDo something in here", "H O T K E Y", MB_OK);
               CTRL_key=0;
            }



        printf("lpszKeyName = %s\n",  lpszKeyName );
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook,    nCode,wParam,lParam);
}

void MessageLoop()
{
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI my_HotKey(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!hInstance) hInstance = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR) lpParm);
    if (!hInstance) return 1;

    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx (  WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC) KeyboardEvent,   hInstance,  NULL    );
    MessageLoop();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)   my_HotKey, (LPVOID) argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);

    //ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);

    if (hThread) return WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);
    else return 1;

}
```